# How can I get the current URLof the site, not a HTTPRequst

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, request

In CodeIgniter the $this->uri->segment()- returns the url of the current request of AJAX, but i want to get the url where the user are now. How can i get it?? maybe it is the previous request?

Answer (score 2):

You could include `window.location` in your AJAX request.